# "Илья" во множественном числе и в родительном падеже

Tags: множественное-число, родительный-падеж, ономастика

Какая у слова "Илья" правильная форма множественного числа родительного падежа?

Множественное число от имен собственных вообще редко встречается, но все же возможно, например, в предложении "У меня нет знакомых Маш". Как заменить в этом предложении слово "Маша" на слово "Илья"?

Конечно, всегда можно сказать "У меня нет знакомых по имени Илья", но это не решает проблему, а обходит ее стороной.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

На многих ресурсах указывается правильный вариант "**Илей**".

Например на [грамотеру](http://forum.gramota.ru/forum/read.php?f=14&i=11894&t=11891) - Ильям, **Илей**, Ильями, Ильях.

Форма "Ильёв" является неправильной и вот как [решена](http://nauka.relis.ru/56/9810/56810127.htm) в журнале "Наука и жизнь":

> "Собственные имена редко употребляются во множественном числе, но обратимся к нарицательным существительным типа: бадья, ладья, попадья, тулья, судья, статья и др. Формы родительного множественного от них: бадей, ладей, судей, статей и др. Значит, от Илья будет... Илей. Эти формы образованы с нулевым окончанием и беглой гласной, на которой и оказывается ударение. В привычных, часто употребляемых формах мы все это легко "проделываем", но при необходимости образовать родительный множественного от собственного имени Илья произошла заминка. (И не у Саши Пчелкина, конечно, а у самого Валентина Катаева.) Форма Ильей образована без беглой гласной с окончанием -ей, а это окончание не должно выступать после конечной согласной основы j (йот) (именно на j кончается основа имени Илья): ведь от слова край, например, образуется форма краев (а не краей). Так почему же неправильна форма Ильев? Потому что окончание -ов (-ев) не образует родительный множественного от существительных с исходной формой (именительным единственного) на -а (-я)."

Comment: А на какой слог ударение?

Comment: @Olga на второй

Comment: Ой, а почему? У "судья"-"судей" оно переходит.

Comment: @Olga http://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C%D1%8F

Comment: а, хорошо. Зализняк всегда прав.

Comment: -1, this is tatally weird. If Илья was a feminine name or the name was Иля, then I agree with Илей. But for a masculine name it is totally wrong.

Comment: @Anixx before downvoting and state something "weird" probably it is more friendly to try to search and give us Reference for any other more sophisticated answer.

Comment: @Ilan If I saw Илей I would understand it as a form of Иля, not Илья.

Comment: @Anixx I understand what you "feel", but the answer here are not "feelings". Do you have a reference to better answer? Do you see Fadeev's thoughts about the topic? The answer given - was based on research and referenced as well.

Comment: I vote for Илий. Think Иеремия, Захария. Илья is a contraction of Илия.

Comment: @Olga, Зализняк допускает оба варианта, су́дей и суде́й (и он, как всегда, прав). Вот фото соответствующей страницы 6-го издания словаря: https://goo.gl/Mq2py2 Общая же закономерность для слов -ья, -ье, -ьё – под ударением -ей: баде́й, ладе́й, стате́й, скаме́й, попаде́й, без ударения -ий: ке́лий (от ке́лья), ко́пий (от копьё), зда́ний, Да́рий (от Да́рья), Ма́рий (от Ма́рья). Исключения: ру́жей, су́дей. Мари́й (от Мари́я), Росси́й (от Росси́я) и т.п. не попадают под это правило, т.к. они не на -ья, а на -ия (нет беглой гласной). Таким образом: Илия́ (пророк) – Или́й, а Илья́ – Иле́й.

Answer (score 7):

*Или́й*. Вы же не будете пытаться образовать форму *Марей* от *Марья* или *Дарей* от *Дарья*, но возьмете формы *Марий* и *Дарий* от полногласных *Мария* и *Дария*.

Пока без источников. Так что возможно, это не более, чем мое добросовестное заблуждение, но мне до сего дня в голову не приходил иной возможный вариант.

Comment: I would put the stress to the first syllable.

Comment: I think that it is the correct form for pl. gen. Илия, but I also have a hard time finding it in any dictionary.